# Ruby Regex: How to match (named) groups inside square brackets?

Tags: ruby, regex, option-type, capture, brackets

I'm trying to write a regex in Ruby that will parse various date/time formats. The entire regex looks like this:

```
/^(?<year>\d{4})\-(?<month>\d{2})\-(?<day>\d{2})(T(?<hour>\d{2})(:(?<minute>\d{2})(:(?<second>\d{2}(\.\d{1,3})?))?)?)?(?<offset>[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})?$/
```

I'm using named groups so that I can fetch the matching parts out of the match object just using the simple names like "year", "month", "day", etc.  This regex is working fine, but let's focus on the "offset" at the end of this:

```
(?<offset>[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})?
```

The problem is that I'm trying to add the ability to interpret a "Z" on the end of the string to denote UTC time (aka Zulu Time).  This "Z" should be mutually exclusive with the offset.  Here's some of the ways I've tried it:

```
(?<offset>[Z([+-]\d{2}:\d{2})])?
(?<offset>[(Z)([+-]\d{2}:\d{2})])?
[(?<zulu>Z)(?<offset>[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})]?
```

None of these work.  In the first two cases, it can interpret date strings ending in "Z", but it can no longer interpret date string ending with actual offsets like "-07:00".  In the third case, the named groups "zulu" and "offset" are just totally missing from the match object.

I think this issue is because I'm trying use square brackets to denote `[(ThisGroup)(OrThisGroup)]?` but I don't think the regex engine appreciates having groups inside of square brackets.  How do I tell the regex engine to allow and capture "group A or group B or neither, but not both"?

Comment: Can you post some sample strings you want to match against with expected results for clarity? Also, are none of the built-in time parsers good enough for your task, such as `Time.strptime`?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. Why not use `Date.parse`?

Comment: `strptime` doesn't do any automatic parsing, it requires a format string (which is basically what I'm building here), also it's on the `Date` and `DateTime` objects, not the `Time` object. Ruby's `Date.parse` is unfortunately not very robust, unlike Python's `dateutil.parser.parse`, which is too bad since I generally prefer Ruby to Python. Escaping the `+` and `-` in the brackets was a good idea, but I just tried it and it had the same results. I guess that's not too surprising since I didn't escape them in the original regex and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets are used for "exactly one of any of these characters" -- that's not what you need here. Pattern-level alternation is done via the `|` operator: `(hello|goodbye) world` will match either `hello world` or `goodbye world`.

```
(?<offset>Z|[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})?
```

Specifically to parse a datetime, though, I suggest preferring `DateTime.parse` (plus `to_time`, if you need a Time instance). And if that isn't sufficiently flexible, consider the [chronic](https://rubygems.org/gems/chronic) gem.

Comment: `Date#parse` and `DateTime#parse` do not always give results that one expects: `Date.parse "It appears that Theresa May is not especially fond of Mr. Trump" #=> #<Date: 2018-05-01 ((2458240j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: @matthewd That's exactly what I needed, thanks! This works like a charm!